# how can I search an element in Skip-List

Tags: algorithm, skip-lists

i'm looking for a way to find in a skip list an element x given, which is the k-th in the list(there are k-1 elements before it). 
The expected time of the algorithm should be O(log K)

i found the Known Algorithm which take O(log n) but here it's O(log K).

thanking you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to augment the skiplist so that each node has a count of the elements in its "subtree" (the elements to its downward-right position up to the next node in its level).

It's very easy to see that you can augment this info without altering the complexity of the list's operations.

Once you have this metadata, you need to go on a level only up to the point where the node on the next level already is too far to the right. At this point, go one level down.

---

Incidentally, this problem is known as *dynamic order statistics* through *augmentation*. I've never seen it with skiplists, but you can find gazoogles of links on how to do it with other ordered trees, and it's pretty much the same idea.